# Why are these pointer different?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I declared these two pointers:

```
int (*ptrNumeros)[5];
int* ptrTest;
```

and initialized both to point to the same array. When i try to print the values (not the addresses), one prints the value and the other the address.
Te same for initialization, ptrTest allow me to do:

```
ptrTest = numeros;
```

but ptrNumeros needs the ampersand or it throws a warning.

Here its the code.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main(){
   //array to test
   int numeros[5];
   numeros[0]=97;
   numeros[1]=387;
   numeros[2]=56;

   //declaration and initialization
   int (*ptrNumeros)[5];
   int* ptrTest;
   ptrTest = numeros;
   ptrNumeros = numeros;

   //different result
   printf("ptrNumeros address: %d\n", ptrNumeros);
   printf("ptrTest address: %d\n\n", ptrTest);
   printf("inside ptrNumeros address: %d\n", *(ptrNumeros));
   printf("inside ptrTest address: %d\n", *(ptrTest));

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2397792/315052) answer your question? Note that `ptrNumeros` is a pointer to array of `int`, while `ptrTest` is a pointer to `int`.